# Can I configure Office Calendar to not display an event over the weekend?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have a meeting that spans a weekend datewise, but not working day wise.  The event as it's displayed implies those are working days even though I have it set as M-F.[image: outlook calendar evnent]

In this example I want "Activity" to be displayed only on the week days.  I still need to see Saturday and Sunday as empty.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the method in the thread below could be helpful to you.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_other-mso_o365b/setting-up-recurring-appointments-in-calendar-365/be858921-da4e-49d7-815d-c93054b3d26c